# Does Rails have *zero* concurrency by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, concurrency, mutex, rack

I'm working on some middleware for rails, working with a pretty recent version:

```
pfernand-2-mn:~ pfernand$ rails -v
Rails 3.1.2
```

This is the output of `rake middleware`:

```
use ActionDispatch::Static
** use Rack::Lock **
use ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache
use Rack::Runtime
use Rails::Rack::Logger
use ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
use ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
use Rack::Sendfile
use ActionDispatch::Callbacks
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
use ActiveRecord::QueryCache
use ActionDispatch::Cookies
use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
use ActionDispatch::Flash
use ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
use Rack::MethodOverride
use ActionDispatch::Head
use ActionDispatch::BestStandardsSupport
run MyApp::Application.routes
```

The thing is that the second component, `Rack::Lock` is, [as far as I know](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Lock.html#call-method), a **mutex wrapping the whole frigging rails stack (!)**.

Does this mean that there's no concurrency in rails, no matter what platform you're using? (I'm using JRuby).

I know I can delete the lock with:

`config.middleware.delete(Rack::Lock)`

But sadly that breaks everything. Does that mean my app is not threadsafe?

Comment: Short history: rails 2 wasn't, everyone claimed it isn't possible, merb proved otherwise, got merged into rails 3, so 3 should be.

Comment: That's rails3 right there and it has a mutex around the whole stack. Tell me how that is considered mutlithreaded

Comment: How does it break everything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should see the following entry in config/environments/production.rb

```
  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!
```

Uncomment in a JRuby or other thread-friendly environment to deploy in threadsafe mode.

Comment: That actually removes `Rack::Lock` from the middleware stack. Is there documentation anywhere that shows what that line does? (aside from removing the lock, which by itself is not enough)

Comment: It was documented in the Rails Guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-middleware, last time I looked.  Perhaps not in as much detail as it sounds like you're interested in, however.  Unfortunately this has only been a theoretical option for me so I've never followed up on it.